# Forward to remote syslog in CoreOS

Tags: logging, syslog, coreos

I want to aggregate CoreOS logs to Papertrail service, which basically provides a syslog endpoint for aggregate logging.

[Common advice](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-centralized-logging-from-systemd/) for this setup seems to be starting a service that does something like this:

```
journalctl -f | ncat --ssl <host>.papertrailapp.com <port>
```

But it's not ideal, as it doesn't handle restarts and remote endpoint downtime very well, because it doesn't have anything like `rsyslogd`'s pooling, so I'll get duplicate logs and/or drop logs.

Given that CoreOS has no package management, is there a conventional way to solve this painlessly?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating such service, enable it and start

```
[Unit]
Description=Papertrail
After=systemd-journald.service
Requires=systemd-journald.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "journalctl -f | ncat --ssl logsN.papertrailapp.com XXXXX"
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```